# _.extend method returns "place is not defined" in Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, templates, exception, underscore.js

I am very novice in JS.

I am trying to execute following call:

```
this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
```

in debug I see that

```
_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj)
```

returns

```
Object {terminalId: 3, city: Object, street: "Победы", houseNumber: "5", cost: 1…}city: Objectid: 1name: "Москва"__proto__: Objectclazz: "all"clazz2: ""cost: 1description: "Третий терминал"houseNumber: "5"id: 3mapLat: 55.57834420000001mapLng: 37.59668899999999numberOfCase: 0numberOfEmptyCase: 0numberShow: 0street: "Победы"terminalId: 3timeOfShow: 0__proto__: Object
```

afer in console I see

```
Uncaught ReferenceError:     place is not defined              VM141:16
      (anonymous function)                                     VM141:16
      template                                                 underscore.js:1269
      window.MARC.addTerminalPage.showTerminalsMain.           addTerminal:792
      renderTerminalsOnMap                                     addTerminal:1144
      k                                                        jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
      l.                                                       fireWith jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
      y jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2send.d
```

What the reason of the problem and how to fix it?

### Update:

more details:

```
message: "place is not defined"stack: "ReferenceError: place is not defined↵    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/resources/js/underscore.js:1261:16), <anonymous>:16:9)↵    at Object._.template.template [as compiled] (http://localhost:9090/resources/js/underscore.js:1269:21)↵    at Object.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:6)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:732:103)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:665:34)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:783:21)↵    at Object.window.MARC.addTerminalPage.showTerminalsMain (http://localhost:9090/member/createCompany/addTerminal:792:50)↵    at Object.renderTerminalsOnMap [as success] (http://localhost:9090/member/createCompany/addTerminal:1144:37)↵    at p.Callbacks.k (http://localhost:9090/resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:16920)↵    at Object.p.Callbacks.l.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:9090/resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:17707)"
```

Comment: What is VM141? Is 'place' some variable that you are using in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

template contains `{{ place }}` fragment.

```
_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj)
```

should contains `place` field.